# Convert from String to BigInteger in C# without cutting off leading zero's.

Tags: c#, asp.net

Working on a project where I need to do a bitwise & between two similar 168 character bitarrays. I am working in C# and when I attempt to convert from String to BigInteger, the leading zero's are being truncated. Is there anything I can do to save these characters?

Basically:

```
string bits = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

BigInteger bigIntBits = BigInteger.Parse(bits);
// I am being returned 1111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Anything will help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `BigInteger` for this purpose? Why not use `bool` arrays?

Comment: Tbh no clue, haven’t ever worked with them. Will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
string bits = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
 // convert to big integer
 var bigIntBits = BigInteger.Parse(bits);
 int index = bits.IndexOf('1');            
 string backToString = new string('0', index) + bigIntBits.ToString();
```